# An out-of-memory error in clustering

Tags: java, out-of-memory, cluster-analysis

I am taking a course on Coursera,and this is the task which I was given:

```
In this question your task is again to run the clustering algorithm from   
lecture, but on a MUCH bigger graph. So big, in fact, that the distances 
(i.e., edge costs) are only defined implicitly, rather than being provided 
as an explicit list.

The data set is below.

clustering_big.txt
The format is:

[# of nodes] [# of bits for each node's label]

[first bit of node 1] ... [last bit of node 1]

[first bit of node 2] ... [last bit of node 2]

...

For example, the third line of the file "0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 
1 0 1 1 0 1" denotes the 24 bits associated with node #2.

The distance between two nodes u and v in this problem is defined as the 
Hamming distance--- the number of differing bits --- between the two nodes' 
labels. For example, the Hamming distance between the 24-bit label of node 
#2 above and the label "0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1" is 
3 (since they differ in the 3rd, 7th, and 21st bits).

The question is: what is the largest value of k such that there is a k-
clustering with spacing at least 3? That is, how many clusters are needed to 
ensure that no pair of nodes with all but 2 bits in common get split into 
different clusters?

NOTE: The graph implicitly defined by the data file is so big that you 
probably can't write it out explicitly, let alone sort the edges by cost. So 
you will have to be a little creative to complete this part of the question. 
For example, is there some way you can identify the smallest distances 
without explicitly looking at every pair of nodes?
```

The link to the dataset is [here](https://d3c33hcgiwev3.cloudfront.net/_fe8d0202cd20a808db6a4d5d06be62f4_clustering_big.txt?Expires=1485993600&Signature=jLMunqnKtmYpuleRY2o-oPpNZbHcyh~~EnvbAH9K6jWYaFrKkKTxoQWbgb74UGyEsW-2rtG~muMx1nxArw0ZolcaKCXDZX28C2WyX8byCJ23HNfw21AiwfgmFYV01Nr549EjK8L8IkNLANAev-64nKnKJ7ZaAetqLdE1FqicyrE_&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJLTNE6QMUY6HBC5A).

The approach I have taken to solving this problem is fittingly described here:

```
For each vertex, generate and store all Hamming distances that are 0, 1 and 
2 units apart. There is only 1 code point that is 0 units apart (which is 
the same code as the vertex), 24C1 = 24 possible code points that are 1 unit 
apart and there are 24C2 = 276 possible code points that are 2 units apart 
for each vertex.

Now, put all vertexes along with their assigned code into a hash table. Use 
the code as the hash table key, with the vertex number as the value - note 
that some codes are not unique (i.e. more than one vertex can be associated 
with the same code), so each key in the hash table will have to potentially 
hold more than one vertex - we will use this hash table later to look up the 
vertex number(s) given the corresponding Hamming code in O(1) time.

Then execute the following steps:


For each vertex (200K iterations):
   For each code that is 0 units apart from 
   this vertex: (1 iteration - there is only one such code
   which is the same code as that of the vertex itself)
       - Use the code to index into the hash table and 
         get the corresponding vertexes if they exist. 
       - Add these 2 vertexes to a cluster.

For each vertex (200K iterations):
   For each code that is 1 unit apart from 
   this vertex: (24 iterations)
       - Use the code to index into the hash table and 
         get the corresponding vertexes if they exist. 
       - Add these 2 vertexes to a cluster.

For each vertex (200K iterations):
   For each code that is 2 units apart from
   this vertex: (276 iterations)
       - Use the code to index into the hash table and 
         get the corresponding vertexes if they exist.
       - Add these 2 vertexes to a cluster.

You are now left with clusters that are at least 3 units apart.
In the first loop, we are essentially clustering all vertexes that are a      
distance of 0 units apart, in the second loop and third loop we are 
clustering vertexes that are 1 unit apart, and 2 units apart respectively 
(this is similar to sorting by edge weights and then combining the vertexes 
into clusters). The above code can be made much more compact - I have split 
up the three main loops for readability.

The time complexity of the above is 200k + (200k * 24) + (200k * 276) = 200k 
* 301 = O(301n) iterations, plus for each iteration, we have to fix up the 
leader pointers of the smaller cluster - which gives us a final complexity 
of O(301nlog n). The space complexity is about O(301n).
```

And here is my implementation of this approach:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.*;
public class bits_k_clustering {
    public static class Vertex{

        private int leader;

        public Vertex(int u_leader)
        {

            leader = u_leader;

        }

        public void UpdateLeader(int newLeader)
        {
            leader = newLeader;
        }

    }

    public static class UnionFind{
        private ArrayList<Vertex> vertices;
        private int clustersCnt;
        private ArrayList<Integer> clustersSize;

        public UnionFind(ArrayList<Vertex> u_vertices)
        {
            vertices = u_vertices;
            clustersCnt = vertices.size();
            clustersSize = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for(int i =0;i<200000;i++)
            {
                clustersSize.add(1);
            }
        }

        public void Union(Vertex x,Vertex y)
        {
            int leader1 = x.leader;
            int leader2 = x.leader;
            if(leader1!=leader2)
            {
                clustersCnt-=1;
                if(clustersSize.get(leader1)>clustersSize.get(leader2))
                {
                    clustersSize.set(leader1,clustersSize.get(leader1)+clustersSize.get(leader2));
                    for(int i = 0;i<200000;i++)
                    {
                        if(vertices.get(i).leader==leader2)
                        {
                            vertices.get(i).UpdateLeader(leader1);
                        }
                    }
                    clustersSize.set(leader2,0);

                }
                else
                {
                    clustersSize.set(leader2, clustersSize.get(leader1)+clustersSize.get(leader2));
                    for(int i = 0;i<200000;i++)
                    {
                        if(vertices.get(i).leader==leader1)
                        {
                            vertices.get(i).UpdateLeader(leader2);
                        }
                    }
                    clustersSize.set(leader1,0);
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String [] bits = new String[200000];
        ArrayList<Vertex> vertices = new ArrayList<Vertex>();
try{
    File file = new File("C:/Users/dadi/Desktop/K-Clustering.txt");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(file);
    in.nextLine();
    for(int i = 0;i<200000;i++)
    {
        String[] strarray = in.nextLine().split(" ");
        String mayhew = "";
        for(int j =0;j<strarray.length;j++)
        {
            mayhew+=strarray[j];
        }
        bits[i] = mayhew;
        vertices.add(new Vertex(i));
    }
    in.close();
    System.out.println("Buildup done,dists zero complete!");
}
catch(IOException ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}

String [][] dist1=new String[200000][24];
for(int i =0;i<200000;i++)
{

    for(int j = 0;j<24;j++)
    {
        char[] x = bits[i].toCharArray();
        if(x[j]=='0')
        {
            x[j]='1';
        }
        else
        {
            x[j]='0';
        }
        dist1[i][j]=String.valueOf(x);
    }
}
System.out.println("Dists one complete!");
String [][] dist2 = new String[200000][276];
for(int i = 0;i<200000;i++)
{
    int z = 0;
    for(int j = 0;j<23;j++)
    {
        for(int k = j+1;k<24;k++)
        {
            char [] x = bits[i].toCharArray();

            if(x[j]=='0' && x[k]=='0')
            {
                x[j]='1';
                x[k]='1';
            }
            else if(x[j]=='0' && x[k]=='1')
            {
                x[j]='1';
                x[k]='0';
            }
            else if(x[j]=='1' && x[k]=='0')
            {
                x[j]='0';
                x[k]='1';
            }
            else if(x[j]=='1' && x[k]=='1')
            {
                x[j]='0';
                x[k]='0';
            }
            dist2[i][z]=String.valueOf(x);
            z++;

        }
    }
}
System.out.println("Dists two complete!");
Map<String,ArrayList<Integer> > nodes = new HashMap<String,ArrayList<Integer> >();
for(int i =0;i<200000;i++)
{
    ArrayList<Integer> xef = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    nodes.put(bits[i],xef);
}
for(int i = 0;i<200000;i++)
{
    ArrayList<Integer> mef = nodes.get(bits[i]);
    mef.add(i);
    nodes.put(bits[i], mef);
}
System.out.println("Map complete!");
UnionFind uf = new UnionFind(vertices);
for(int i = 0;i<200000;i++)
{
    ArrayList<Integer> def = nodes.get(bits[i]);
    if(def.size()>1)
    {
        for(int j = 0;j<def.size();j++)
        {
            if(i==def.get(j))
            {
                continue;
            }
            uf.Union(vertices.get(i), vertices.get(def.get(j)));
        }
    }
}
System.out.println("Spacing zero clustered!");
for(int i = 0;i<200000;i++)
{
    for(int j = 0;j<24;j++)
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> nef = nodes.get(dist1[i][j]);
        if(nef!=null)
        {
            for(int k = 0;k<nef.size();k++)
            {
                uf.Union(vertices.get(i), vertices.get(nef.get(k)));
            }
        }
    }
}
System.out.println("Spacing one clustered!");
for(int i = 0;i<200000;i++)
{
    for(int j =0;j<276;j++)
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> oef = nodes.get(dist2[i][j]);
        if(oef!=null)
        {
            for(int k =0;k<oef.size();k++)
            {
                uf.Union(vertices.get(i), vertices.get(oef.get(k)));
            }
        }
    }
}
System.out.println("Spacing two clustered!");
System.out.println(uf.clustersCnt);

    }

}
```

However,when the program is running,it gets smoothly to the 'bulding dists two' stage,at which point it slows down a lot,until it finally throws out this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
at java.lang.String.toCharArray(Unknown Source)
at bits_k_clustering.main(bits_k_clustering.java:137)
```

I have changed the Eclipse.ini settings to -Xmx1024m for maximum memory heap sizes,but it still throws out this error.I don't know why it throws out this error (the memheap should have enough memory for the matrix by default),so why does this error show up and how can I fix it?

Comment: You're asking us to do what you're supposed to do. If you have specific questions, you're welcome to ask them here. "Optimize this for me" is not a specific question.

Comment: I forgot to specify my question.Duly noted,thank you.

Comment: `GC overhead limit exceeded` means you're creating garbage faster than the GC can collect it.

Comment: I don't know whether the error is caused only by the 'building dists two' phase of the program,or the collective garbage dumping of the program.I tend towards the first option,because it takes disproportionately more time to build dists of 2 than to build dists of 1(the dataset is a lot bigger,but the running time is a lot slower than it should be necessary until the program throws the error).

Comment: It's caused by an ineffective algorithm.

Comment: Well,what are your propositions for fixing it?

Comment: It's your coursework, not mine. Why would I care if it works or not? I told you "optimize this for me" is not a specific question. Not even if you change the wording a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

1. `toCharArray` will *copy* the `String` into a `char[]` every time, entirely unnecessary.
2. Don't use `String` to store *bits* or numbers. If you have less than 32 bits, use an `int`. If you have less than 64 bits, use a `long`. If more, use a `long[]`.
3. Try some optimizations based on bit operations. For example, you can compute the Hamming distance with a simple bit count and xor operation. You can also get a cheap lower bound based on the number of set bits - if one has 6 bits, the other 2, at least 4 bits have to be different.
4. Avoid `ArrayList<Integer>` and `ArrayList<Vertex>`. These need roughly 20 bytes per integer rather than 4.  That is 400% overhead. Use `int[]`+`size`, double array if full (ArrayList does the same, but uses boxed integers).

Use a profiler such as visualvm to see where you wastw memory.

My guess is that `String [][] dist2 = new String[200000][276];` is to blame. 200000*276*50 is probably enough to eat all your memory. Get rid of useless strings!